# Mongoose: which are the Number type limits?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building a node app, with mongodb through mongoose.

I define a 'phone' field of type `Number` for my person model.
I save ~550 persons with no problem.
When I try to save a person with a specific number ("3932978***", last 3 digits obscured for privacy reasons), I get a cast error:‬

```
... at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)","message":"Cast to Number failed for value \"3932978***‬\" at path \"phone\"","name":"CastError","kind":"Number","value":"3932970***‬","path":"phone"}}}
```

Is it possible I'm hitting a Mongoose `Number` limit? Effectively, that number seems to be the biggest among other phone number values, but it is not near a power of 2...

I am completely confused... Can you shed some light?

**UPDATE**: I add the Javascript code I use, as requested in comments...

File `models/person.js`:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  key: String,
  providerKey: String,
  name: String,
  phone: Number,
  ...
},
{
  autoIndex: config.debug,
  collection: 'persons'
});
personSchema.index({ providerKey: 1, key: 1 }, { unique: true });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

...
```

File `controllers/person.js`:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
var Person = require('../models/person');
...

var upsert = function(person, callback) {
  Person.findOne(
    { providerKey: person.providerKey, key: person.key },
    function(err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        log.warn('could not find person ', person.name, ':', err);
        return callback(err);
      }
      if (doc) { // person did already exist
        _.merge(doc, person);
      } else { // person did not exist before
        doc = new Person();
        _.merge(doc, person);
      }
      doc.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          log.warn('could not save person ', doc.providerKey, ' ', doc.key, ':', err);
          return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null);
      });    
    }
  );
};

...

var person = {};
person.phone = getParseNormalizePhoneAndReturn10DigitsStringOrNull();
upsert(person, function(err) {
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps...

**UPDATE 2**:
I am using node v0.12.7 and mongoose 4.1.12.
The first "number" that causes a cast error is "3932978***", while the biggest one *not* causing any error is "3927983***".
I must add that I did just notice in the `person` collection there are some 'floating point' numbers (when starting to populate the collection, the normalization function had probably some issues, and some `dot` had not been removed... So I have a couple of numbers like this: "320.2264***", if this could someway help...

Comment: why aren't you saving phone numbers as strings?

Comment: Can you show us your JS code? Not just the error

Comment: are your other phone numbers also sent as strings?

Comment: @inspired: Yes, I'll do it... I thought `Number` could be a more compact type to store 10 or 14 digits numbers (of course phone numbers are normalized, before storing...). But the question is about a possible Mongoose problem (possibly, even if not very probable... :-), so I suppose it is worth answering in substance...

Comment: @Jorge Aranda: Yes, the code to get, normalize and store phone numbers is one.

Comment: @Drown: Yes, of course (sorry for not having done it in the first place)... I've updated the question right now...

Comment: Two more questions: what is the next biggest value that successfully casts to a number? And what versions of node and mongoose are you using?

Comment: @Jorge Aranda: just updated question with these details...